# remove Duplicated data from very huge table

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, sql-insert

I have a table contains more than 500 millions records in MySQL database  ,
i need to remove duplicated from it ,
i tried this query on table contain 20 millions , it was ok but for the 500 millions it take very long time :

```
-- Create temporary table   
CREATE TABLE temp_table LIKE names_tbles;

-- Add constraint    
ALTER TABLE temp_table ADD UNIQUE(name , family);

-- Copy data     
INSERT IGNORE INTO temp_table SELECT * FROM names_tbles;
```

is there better solution ?

Comment: What columns do you have in the table?

Comment: i have 3 :id , name , family , i need to get unique name and family

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is aggregation rather than `insert ignore`. That way, there is no need for the database to manage rejected records:

```
insert into temp_table(id, name, family)
select min(id), name, family 
from names_tbles
group by id, family;
```

I would take one step further and suggest adding the unique constraints only after the table is populated, so there is no need for the database to check for duplicates (the query guarantees that already), which should speed up the `insert` statement.

Comment: Even though this will work technically, the request seems "unclear" to me... You just can't drop 50.000 "John Doe", cause they already exist with different ids. 

A key on firstname / lastname is a natural key, and therefore should not be forced to be a unique key.